# Zend Framework 3 Redirect from factory

Tags: zend-framework3

My **Controller** has a **Factory** that gives it a **Form**

```
    $formManager = $container->get('FormElementManager');

    return new MyController(
        $formManager->get(MyForm::class)        
    );
```

My **Form** has also a **Factory** that gives it an **AuthenticationService**

```
    return new MyForm(
        $container->get(AuthenticationService::class)
    );
```

That way I can check in the form if the user has identity.
But how can i redirect him from the form?
Just like in a Controller?

```
    if(!$authService->hasIdentity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myRoute);
    }
```

Or how can i redirect from a (**Controller** and/or **Form**) **Factory**?

Comment: Isn 't that the wrong approach? Why not injecting the controller with the auth service and the form and checking in the controller, if a user has the rights to access the form? You don 't have to access the auth service in a form instance. Just keep your business logic in the controller.

Comment: I'm checking in the controller also but when i inject the form to the controller inside the form i inject connection the the DB so that i can automatically fill some `selects` by using my identity (get the userId). So the Form comes first and the Controller second. If the session is expired i can't get the userId and my code breaks. 

One way that i fix this is i just check in the form if it's expired. If not don't fill any `selects`. 
So that way it gets to the Controller next and can redirect me to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for your issue could be the possibilty of using the `build` method with the factory call.

You haven 't shown your factories, so I will use some standard examples, which explain the solution.

The first approach is not injecting the whole form to the controller. Instead just inject the form element manager. So you can use the build method of the factory inside your controller.

**The controller factory**

```
namespace Application\Controller\Factory;

use Application\Controller\YourController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class YourControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $formElementManager = $container->get('FormElementManager');
        return new YourController($formElementManager);
    }
}
```

This differs from your original factory. Only the form element manager is injected to the controller. This holds a few advantages for you. One of this is the build method of the manager.

**The Controller**

```
namespace Application\Controller;

class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $formElementManager;

    public function __construct($formElementManager)
    {
         $this->formElementManager = $formElementManager;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $user = $this->currentUser();

        if ($user === null) {
             $this->redirect('to/somewhere/the/user/belongs');
        }

        // here 's the magic!
        $form = $this->formElementManager->build(YourForm::class, [
            'userID' => $user->getUserId(),
        ]);

        // some form stuff follows here
    }
}
```

As the form was not injected directly to your controller but the form element manager, you can use the form element manager instead inside the controller. This offers you the opportunity to use the build function. With this function you can add some options to your form factory. In this case I 'm using the user id for the form factory.

If there 's no valid user, no form will be created because an exception is thrown before.

**The Form Factory**

The form factory creates a new instance of your form. All needed dependencies should be created in the factory. How the build function works here, I 'll explain later in the answer.

```
namespace Application\Form\Factory;

use Application\Form\YourForm;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class YourFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $selectOptions = [];

        if ($options !== null) {
             if (isset($options['userID])) {
                 $tablegateway = $container->get(YourTableGateway::class);
                 $selectOptions = $tablegateway->findOptionsByUserId($options['userID]);
             }
        }

        $form = $container->get(YourForm::class);

        if (count($selectOptions))
        $form->get('YourSelectElement')->setValueOptions($selectOptions);

        return $form;
    }
}
```

This factory does all you need. Via the build method you hand over the user id. If a user id is present a table gateway is created from wich you retrieve select options by the given user id. These options will be set to the form field. This logic is kept in the factory to keep the form class itself clean and simple.

With this solution you don 't need the auth service in your form. Your form is only generated when a valid user id is given. Your form instance will not crash, if there 's no user id given. The only conceivable case could be a form with default or no select options for the specific field.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Looking at the 
`$form->get('YourSelectElement')->setValueOptions($selectOptions);`

how can i set Validator the same way (Lets say `between`)?

Comment: That's something the Validator Chain of the specific element in the form needs to be assigned to. Like `$form->getInputFilter()->get('YourSelectElement')->getValidatorChain()->attach($validatorObject)`.